# construct a pairwise matrix from a vector in tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, matrix

Suppose that I have a 1*3 vector `[[1,3,5]]` (or a list like `[1,3,5]` if you with), how do I generate a 9*2 matrix: `[[1,1],[1,3],[1,5],[3,1],[3,3],[3,5],[5,1],[5,3],[5,5]]`?

Elements in the new matrix is the pairwise combination of elements in the original matrix.

Also, the original matrix could be with zeros, like this `[[0,1],[0,3],[0,5]]`.

The implementation should generalise to vectors of any dimensionalities.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tf.meshgrid()` and `tf.transpose()` to  generate two matrices. Then reshape and concat them.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([[1,3,5]])

A,B=tf.meshgrid(a,tf.transpose(a))
result = tf.concat([tf.reshape(B,(-1,1)),tf.reshape(A,(-1,1))],axis=-1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(result))

[[1 1]
 [1 3]
 [1 5]
 [3 1]
 [3 3]
 [3 5]
 [5 1]
 [5 3]
 [5 5]]
```

Comment: The tf.reshape(B,(-1,1)) is interesting, I did not find a similar example of this usage in the official document https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape.

Comment: @clement116 This usage document already exists. Similar to `reshape(t, [2, -1])` and `reshape(t, [-1, 9])` in examples.

Comment: @clement116 You're welcome. Please accept it if you have no question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `product` from `itertools`

```
from itertools import product
np.array([np.array(item) for item in product([1,3,5],repeat =2 )])


array([[1, 1],
       [1, 3],
       [1, 5],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 3],
       [3, 5],
       [5, 1],
       [5, 3],
       [5, 5]])
```

Comment: Thanks! but I am asking about a tensorflow implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I also come up with an answer, similar to @giser_yugang, but not using tf.meshgrid and tf.concat.

```
import tensorflow as tf 

inds = tf.constant([1,3,5])

num = tf.shape(inds)[0]
ind_flat_lower = tf.tile(inds,[num])
ind_mat = tf.reshape(ind_flat_lower,[num,num])
ind_flat_upper = tf.reshape(tf.transpose(ind_mat),[-1])
result = tf.transpose(tf.stack([ind_flat_upper,ind_flat_lower]))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(result))


[[1 1]
 [1 3]
 [1 5]
 [3 1]
 [3 3]
 [3 5]
 [5 1]
 [5 3]
 [5 5]]
```